# Python: How to destroy buttons with the same name (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, button

The loop in the program created a number of buttons with the same name. How to destroy them?

For example:

```
for i in range(5):
    global btn
    btn=Button(text=name,command=startfile_)
    btn.place(x=5,y=5)

def destroy_it():
    btn.destroy()#Its destroying only 1
    
destroy_btn(text=name,command=destroy_it)
```

Comment: Put them in a list?

Answer (score 2):

It strongly depends on your use case. By the way, I suggest you to [ensure your code is reproducible as-is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can adapt our answers to your specific case.

Here some ways to address your problem.

**1.** save all buttons in a list and iterate over the list to delete them

- pros: very easy to use and understand
- cons: you need to pass your list along the code to work on it

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
buttons = []

for i in range(5):
    btn = tk.Button(root, text=f'test{i}', command=None)  # TODO fill with your command
    btn.pack()
    buttons.append(btn)


def destroy_it(buttons):
    # You must know the list of buttons to destroy
    for btn in buttons.copy():
        btn.destroy()
        buttons.remove(btn)  # also delete buttons from the list


tk.Button(root, text="Destroy all buttons", command=lambda: destroy_it(buttons)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**2.** destroy all widgets that satisfy a specific rule (i.e. `Button`s with a specific text)

- pros: you have a large flexibility on the widgets you are going to delete
- cons: you may accidentally delete widgets, you must correctly deal with it

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

for i in range(5):
    btn = tk.Button(root, text=f'test{i}', command=None)  # TODO fill with your command
    btn.pack()


def destroy_it():
    # Iterate over any widget and destroy it if it is a button with text "test....."
    for child in root.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(child, tk.Button) and child['text'].startswith('test'):
            child.destroy()


tk.Button(root, text="Destroy all buttons", command=destroy_it).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**3.** Give your buttons a name and address them by name

- pros: easy to include in the code and to understand
- cons: you must remember the names you used and you may get `KeyError`

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

for i in range(5):
    btn = tk.Button(root, name=f'btn{i}', text=f'test{i}', command=None)  # TODO fill with your command
    btn.pack()


def destroy_it():
    # Get each button by its name
    for i in range(5):
        btn = root.nametowidget(f'.btn{i}')
        btn.destroy()


tk.Button(root, text="Destroy all buttons", command=destroy_it).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

There are probably many other ways to achieve it, such as associating an "autodestroy" method to each button that is triggered by command, or include your buttons in a `Frame` and destroy the frame at once... But you may start from the examples above