# How to remove Tkinter label over mutiple lines that are created by a while loop

Tags: python, tkinter, label

This is my first time asking a question on StackOverFlow.

I created this number table using **Tkinter** which basically returns multiples of a given number till a certain number.

Example:

Number: 2

Till: 3

Output:

1). 2 x 1 = 2

2). 2 x 2 = 4

3). 2 x 3 = 6

Till here the code works perfectly fine for me.

But when I try to generate another number table on the same window, only some labels are replaced with updated labels while the old labels stay there.

I tried making another button to clear the contents, but that too just removes the last label and not all labels.

Can someone help me with this.

Code is as under:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Python")
root.geometry("240x300")


# __Functionality__
def generator(number, till):
    

    current_limit = 1

    while current_limit <= int(till):
        number_table = int(number) * current_limit

        the_table = Label(root, text=f'{current_limit}) {number} x {current_limit} = {number_table}')
        the_table.grid(row=5 + current_limit, sticky=W + E, columnspan=2)
        current_limit += 1


# __Layout__


# Heading:
heading = Label(root, text="Number Table Generator", font=("Tahoma", 15))
heading.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W, padx=(5, 0))

# Number Table:
number_table = Label(root, text="Number: ", font=("Tahoma", 10))
number_table.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=(5, 0))

number_table_get = Entry(root, font=("Tahoma", 10), width=20, borderwidth=2)
number_table_get.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

# Number Table (till):
number_table_till = Label(root, text="Till: ", font=("Tahoma", 10))
number_table_till.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, padx=(5, 0))

number_table_till_get = Entry(root, font=("Tahoma", 10), width=20, borderwidth=2)
number_table_till_get.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

# Generate Table (Button):
generate_table = Button(root, text="Generate Table", font=("Tahoma", 10),
                        command=lambda: generator(number_table_get.get(), number_table_till_get.get()))
generate_table.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E, padx=(5, 0))

# Clear Contents (Button):
generate_table = Button(root, text="Clear", font=("Tahoma", 10))
generate_table.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E, padx=(5, 0))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I assume it's because you only have one variable for all the labels and all the labels before the last one lose their variable so they arent accessible. Try storing all the labels in a list, using `.grid()` in a for loop which iterates through the list and emptying the list on the press of your clear button. I wouldnt recommend using a while-loop in your generator function either

Comment: in your title you also say you use a for-loop yet the code has a while loop?

Comment: You goal should be to delete everything (or at least any label that will not be automatically overwritten) before the next number table. You could follow one of these approaches [https://stackoverflow.com/a/72731215/13541354](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72731215/13541354)

Comment: Thank you guys!

I was able to fix my mistake using, For Loops & Lists.

Comment: @eisa.exe, thank you for your help and special thanks for correcting my title.

Comment: @ALai, thank you for sharing the approach it worked flawlessly.